# MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) hang ups with artifacts on the screen

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

Sometimes my Macbook Pro hang up with the artifacts like on the photo

[image: MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)]
Basically it occur if i move my notebook from one place to another, open-close it and so on. If notebook stay still, this hang ups doesnt occur often. It looks like some mechanical failures inside my notebook. Did you know what a problem is this?

Comment: If it's happening when you move it, there is a bad solder joint on the logic board.  It could be the GPU itself or one of the circuits that feeds the GPU.  It needs to go in for service to a shop that specializes in logic board repairs.  See this related video:  https://twitter.com/BillGates/status/1031329972311535616   Slightly different symptoms, but same premise.